# Change Navigator.pop() animation duration with page_transition

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-routes

To have an animation while changing screens I am using the `page_transition: ^1.1.5`

**Here is an example:**

```
Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft, child: HandymanDocumentsOverview(), duration: Duration(milliseconds: 150)));
```

Yesterday I installed `firebase_core: ^0.5.0` and updated all other Firebase dependencies. And somehow it just feels like the animation speed for `Navigator.pop(context);` is way slower than before and doesn't even match the first animations speed.
Does anyone know how to fix that?

Edit here is my `flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale de-DE)
    • Flutter version 1.22.0 at /Users/bastianmeyer/flutter
    • Framework revision d408d302e2 (3 days ago), 2020-09-29 11:49:17 -0700
    • Engine revision 5babba6c4d
    • Dart version 2.10.0

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/bastianmeyer/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.0, Build version 12A7209
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 45.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.49.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.15.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone SE (2nd generation) (mobile) • FC1FC561-C5E6-4E13-AEE5-B5D9308C29B5 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-0 (simulator)
```

Comment: Are you testing on debug mode or production mode? Debug mode is much slower by default. If you want to make sure if something is causing Jank, you should test in production mode and see if it persists.

Comment: I mean the Screen entering animation is still fast the leaving animation is just way slower than the entering one. Do you have a resource on how I can test on production mode? Or do I just have to build it as I would publish it to testflight?

Comment: You can check [official docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/build-modes). It's "release" mode (not production, my bad).

Comment: Ok, you are right is way better, but still slower than it's supposed to be. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, from thereon you need to isolate the problem. Remove (or downgrade) packages to isolate the faulty one. You should also check if it's on all page transitions or a just few. If you can pinpoint the problem it'll be much easier. You can [check this video by Filip Hracik](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vVg9It7cOfY) about optimizing your app.

Comment: Maybe you ca provide some information like `is rolled back firebase_core help?` or `how slow it become?`

Comment: what if you do it with plain flutter animation and not with an package

Comment: I think this question can be improved by focusing on the problem. I'd start by eliminating other variables like `firebase`. Having a minimal reproducable code would be the quickest way to get an answer.

Answer (score 5):

The package you are using is not yet updated to set the `reverseTransitionDuration` which was added to flutter recently.
You can upvote [this](https://github.com/kalismeras61/flutter_page_transition/issues/30) issue to bring attention to it.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Should be no longer an issue with version `1.1.7+3.`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of specifying the forward and reverse durations:

```dart
Navigator.of(context).push(
  PageRouteBuilder(
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800), // Forward Duration
    reverseTransitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800), // Reverse Duration
    pageBuilder: (BuildContext context,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
      return NewScreen();
    },
    transitionsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
        Widget child) {
      return FadeTransition(
        opacity: animation,
        child: child,
      );
    },
  ),
);
```